# How to use a local link in HTML?

Tags: html

I am learning HTML. I want to know the use of LOCAL LINK in HTML.

Comment: This question isn't very clear. Can you ask a more specific question? What is it you want to know about "local" links (which I assume are relative links?).

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

what are the differences between hyperlink and local link ?

Comment: Are you referring to relative path links or to element anchor? The former is something like href="somepath.html" the latter is like href="#someelementid"

Comment: Can u tell in detail ? what will be the cases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hyperlink is when you make an image clickable and when you click on it, it takes you to another website and a local link is when the file(usually picture) is on your pc or server and your specify the location to make it appear on the webpage.

Example of how to use: /graphics/image.png or 
/help/articles/how-do-i-set-up-a-webpage.html

Another Example: You want to add a picture to your website. So you add it. You are cool so you want to make the image clickable so it can take you to another website. You do that with two usual choices. A local(relative) link or a absolute link.

An absolute link is just a URL. poop.com
A relative link is a path on your server or in your files that leads to the new place in this case: you would put /books.html instead of a URL. IT is a file or picture. hope this helps http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more? Are they both hyperlinks that are clickable but it depends on the location of the resource that is linked to?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the file in the same folder as the html file then put the file name in the link part: e.g. "page2.html"

Insert text to be clicked

http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_links.asp

Answer (score 0):

Local links are used if you have some stuff on your pc/server and you want to link it into your website e.g. pictures,css,js etc. via `<a href="page.php"></a>, <img src="picture.png">, <link href="style.css">` etc.

Or if you want to link from current page, for example from index.php to info.php.
Your link will looks like `<a href="info.php">info</a>`
But only if they are in same folder.
If they are in different folders link will looks like `<a href="path/info.php">info</a>`